# Get value from element above

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working with JQuery and i have a simple question. How do I get the information from the p-tag below?

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p> Hello there </p>
    <p onclick="myFunction()"> Hello </p>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
  var result = $(this).prev('p');
  alert(result)
}
```

But I am getting

```
[object Object]
```

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `console.log`. `alert` cannot print a JS object

Comment: $(this).prev('p').text(); or $(this).prev('p').html();

Answer (score 2):

When you call a function from an `onclick` attribute, `this` is not set to the target element. You need to give the function a parameter, and pass `this` explicitly.

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  var result = $(el).prev('p');
  alert(result.text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Hello there </p>
<p onclick="myFunction(this)"> Hello </p>
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar but why do I need to write .text() in the end?

Comment: FYI you don't pass the `el` argument to the function

Comment: @LMinor because that function returns the innerText of that item. result, by itself is a jQuery object (the result of a jQuery query) and it is to be expected that it will be converted into text as [object Object], unless you override the toString symbol, but that's a different story

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your current code is that `this` within `myFunction()` doesn't refer to the clicked element as you attached the handler with an `on*` event attribute.

To fix this, and improve the logic, use unobtrusive event handlers. As you've already added a reference to jQuery to the page, you can use `click()`, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.foo').click(function() {
    var result = $(this).prev('p').text();
    console.log(result)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello there</p>
<p class="foo">Hello</p>
```

Note that I showed the `text()` property in the example as it's much more succinct than showing the entire object with all its properties. Also, always use `console.log()` for debugging instead of `alert()`, as the latter coerces data types which can mask problems. It's also modal which is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this` in the `onclick` and find its `prev()`

#### HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Hello there </p>
<p onclick="myFunction(this)"> Hello </p>
```

#### Javascript

```
function myFunction(el) {
  alert($(el).prev('p').text());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  result = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML
  alert(result)
}
```

```html
<p id ='myP' onclick="myFunction('myP')"> Hello </p>
```